# Find element by xpath selenium web driver

Tags: html, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage:

```
  <div class="formfonttitle">Wireless - General</div>
    <div style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px"><img       src="/images/New_ui/export/line_export.png"></div>
    <div class="formfontdesc">Set up the wireless related information below.</div>
    <table width="99%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" id="WLgeneral" class="FormTable">
    <tr id="wl_unit_field">
    <th>Frequency</th>
    <td>
    <select name="wl_unit" class="input_option" onChange="_change_wl_unit(this.value);">
    <option class="content_input_fd" value="0" >2.4GHz</option>
    <option class="content_input_fd" value="1" selected>5GHz</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

I am trying to select "2.4GHz" using xpath. By default "5GHz" option is selected. I am doing this from Python script and using selenium webdriver.

I am doing this:

```
elements = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='wl_unit']")
title = elements[1].find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='content_input_fd']")
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running JavaScript with selinum like this

```
mydriver.execute_script("$('.input_option option[value="0"]')")
```

[This](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver) may also help you for selecting an option in python selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath to find the 2.4GHz option element, and then peform 'click' on the element to get it selected :

```
option = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='wl_unit']/option[@value='0']")
option.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

@Manoj
It is under select, so you can use select method which is generally used for dropdown as follows:

You wrote this.
Webelement elements = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='wl_unit']")

Now continue :

Select object = new Select(elements);

object.selectByValue(1);

or

object.selectByVisibleText("5GHz")

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code

```
WebElement wlUnit= WebElement elea= driver.findElement(By.name("wl_unit"));
Select wlSelect = new Select(wlUnit);
wlSelect.selectByValue(0);
```

OR

```
WebElement wlUnit= WebElement elea= driver.findElement(By.name("wl_unit"));
Select wlSelect = new Select(wlUnit);    
wlSelect.selectByVisibleText("2.4GHz");
```